# Sonar Analysis Fails with error Unable to evict preview database in 4.3.2 following schema migration

Tags: sonarqube

We migrated our oracle 11.2 schema to new oracle 11.2 DB server. On running analysis on sonarqube 4.3.2 against new schema fails with following error.

In addition the Server ID is shown as empty in GUI though there is a entry for field sonar.core.id in DB. Not able to generate ID as well. Not sure if this si related.

```
 Unable to evict preview database: /batch_bootstrap/evict?project=724277: Fail to execute request [code=500, url=http://pchiroadmap01.lnx.in.here.com:9000/batch_bootstrap
/evict?project=724277]: Fail to download 
[http://pchiroadmap01.lnx.in.here.com:9000/batch_bootstrap
/evict?project=724277]. Response code: 500 -> [Help 1]
```

**The sonar log shows following exceptions.**

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ORA-00904: "NOTE": invalid identifier
: INSERT INTO properties (prop_key, resource_id, text_value, user_id, name, value, note, id) VALUES('sonar.dryRun.cache.lastUpdate', 724277, empty_clob(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ?)
        /local_data/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
        /local_data/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/oracle/adapter.rb:183:in `ora_insert'
```

Please suggest what can be done.

Thanks,

Jayesh

Comment: Would be interesting to know from which version you did the migration. Did you see any error in logs during migration?

Comment: We have an instance running on 4.3.2 against oracle 11.2 schema which was not on our production database server. So we created a new schema on production server and did an import of the old schema. Now pointing sonar to that schema.

Comment: With initial import we ran into duplicates and analysis would fail with Unique constraint violation errors. However now analysis gets published on dashboard but in the end it fails with DB eviction error.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on [this DDL file](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/4.3.2/sonar-core/src/main/resources/org/sonar/core/persistence/schema-h2.ddl#L220) (from SonarQube 4.3.2), there is no "note" column on the "properties" table - nor "value" nor "name". This means that the following error in your log:

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ORA-00904: "NOTE": invalid identifier
: INSERT INTO properties (prop_key, resource_id, text_value, user_id, name, value, note, id) VALUES('sonar.dryRun.cache.lastUpdate', 724277, empty_clob(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ?)
        /local_data/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
        /local_data/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/oracle/adapter.rb:183:in `ora_insert'
```

indicates that your DB schema has been altered somehow. In such situation, you can't expect SonarQube to work properly.

**Update:**

One thing that might help you: this might be linked to the JDBC user that you are using for SonarQube. Such error can happen if this user is able to access two schema that contains two SonarQube database. So you should check this point.

Comment: Thanks for our response. Yes I see it is trying to write to a non existing columns but why would it do so is unclear. So the question is what can we do to migrate it properly. We tried multiple fresh imports from the working sonar instance schema without any success. After import on comparing existing schema with new schema does not reveal any differences. In any case can you suggest what are my options now as I am stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: I updated the answer with a hint that could help you.

Comment: Sounds really crazy, but if I manually add those extra columns in new schema, I got the server ID generated, the issue of database eviction goes away. I get the proper analysis reported on dashboard without any issues. However I still continue to face this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188082/cannot-display-measure-filter-list-in-sonar-4-3-2-after-schema-migraiton.