# Cannot Display measure_filter_list in Sonar 4.3.2 after Schema Migraiton

Tags: sonarqube

We are using Sonarqube 4.3.2. We migrated the Oracle 11.2 Schema to a different Oracle DB server. After migration when logged in as admin, we get the following:

Error occurred while trying to display the widget "measure_filter_list
I tried changing the database entry to remove sort=links as suggested here. However that does not help.

Can you please suggest what can be done? We do not have an immediate plan to upgrade.

Any help appreciated.

Below is error log.

```
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]  Can not render widget measure_filter_list: cannot convert instance of class org.jruby.RubyString to class java.lang.Long
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/app/models/measure_filter.rb:206:in `execute'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    compiled-template:10:in `_run_inline_332360915_locals_dashboard_configuration_widget_widget_properties'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:269:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/app/helpers/dashboard_helper.rb:161:in `widget_body'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/_widget.html.erb:3:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47_widget46html46erb_locals_object_widget'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:30:in `benchmark'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in `render_partial'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:19:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47index46html46erb'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:15:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47index46html46erb'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyRange.java:427:in `each'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:9:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47index46html46erb'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in `_render_with_layout'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1252:in `render_for_file'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:936:in `render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    jar:file:/misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1328:in `default_render'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1334:in `perform_action'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    jar:file:/misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    file:/misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:58:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    /misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    file:/misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    file:/misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
2015.07.02 09:54:04 ERROR web[rails]    file:/misc-app-data/sonar/sonarqube_uat-4.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your previous question ([Sonar Analysis Fails with error Unable to evict preview database in 4.3.2 following schema migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141787/sonar-analysis-fails-with-error-unable-to-evict-preview-database-in-4-3-2-follow)), your database has been manually altered so you can't expect SonarQube to work properly.